# Display input file without print in awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

My Code is in mid of manipulating two input files.

```
awk -F'|' -v PARM_VAL="${PARM_VALUE[*]}" '
BEGIN { split(PARM_VAL,pa," ") }
FNR==NR
{
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
a[NR,i]=$i;
}

END {printf "second value of SPPIN : "a[2,2]", parm : "pa[2]", File val : " FILENAME "First rec of SPPOUT: " $0 ;printf "\n" } ' SPP_IN SPP_OUT
```

I am passing parm array to awk, storing first input file in array. Just executed the above command.
**My first input file is getting displayed without print. Anyway to suppress or avoid it?**

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do here exactly? You don't seem to process the second (`SPP_OUT`) file anywhere in that script (well you print the last line from that file in the `END` block I suppose). You appear to be printing the second field from the second line of the `SPP_IN` file (after storing the entire file in memory for some reason) and also the second field of the `PARM_VALUE` array and the name of the last file (`SPP_OUT` in this case) that was processed.

Comment: Hi I will compare each column of two files based on PARM_VALUE.

Comment: Compare what to what? What do you do once you compare them? What do you mean your first file is getting printed in the script in the post? What are you trying to get help with here?

Comment: **My concern here is all records of my first input file is displayed even without print statement. How to avoid that.**                                                                                          I am trying to compare first record of both files as per PARM Value.

Comment: @Madan this is your second question demonstrating that you have no idea of the basic syntax of awk. Get the book Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins and at least read the first couple of chapters and try to write a "Hello World" program to get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Don't split `FNR == NR` and the `{` of the action.

```
FNR == NR
{
```

Put them on the same line instead.

```
FNR == NR {
```

`awk` is seeing `FNR==NR` as a pattern without an action and using the default action of `print`.

Comment: Thanks @Etan Resiner. Working Perfect!!                                                       But if i try to print first field of all second file records. I am facing syntax error                                                                                                           `awk -F'|' -v PARM_VAL="${PARM_VALUE[*]}" '
BEGIN { split(PARM_VAL,pa," ") }
FNR==NR{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[NR,i]=$i; }
{print }
if (FILENAME == "SPP_OUT") { print FILENAME , $1 }
END {printf "second value of SPPIN : "a[2,2] ;printf "\n" } ' SPP_IN SPP_OUT
`

Comment: `if` statements go *inside* `{action}` blocks not at the toplevel. And you seem to have a stray `{print}` there which will print every line of every processed file (as written).