# User defined function issue in awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

My code 1 :

```
awk -F'|' -v PARM_VAL="${PARM_VALUE[*]}" '
BEGIN { split(PARM_VAL,pa," ") 
fn_1()
{
print "inside fn"
}
}
FNR==NR{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[NR,i]=$i; }

{if (FILENAME == "SPP_OUT") {print $1}}
fn_1 
END {printf " second value of SPPIN : "a[2,2]} ' SPP_IN SPP_OUT
```

I am getting error  **fatal: function `fn_1' not defined**

My code 2 :

```
awk -F'|' -v PARM_VAL="${PARM_VALUE[*]}" '
BEGIN { split(PARM_VAL,pa," ") 
fn_1()
{
ret = "returned"
return ret
}
}
FNR==NR{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[NR,i]=$i; }

{if (FILENAME == "SPP_OUT") {print $1}}
m=fn_1()
END {printf " second value of SPPIN : "a[2,2];print $m} ' SPP_IN SPP_OUT
```

I am facing 
**awk: cmd. line:6: return  ret
awk: cmd. line:6: ^ `return' used outside function context**

Can any asssist ? 
Thanks

Comment: isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735013/display-input-file-without-print-in-awk ?

Comment: Try to define the function before BEGIN statement as like "awk -F'|' -v PARM_VAL="${PARM_VALUE[*]}" '
fn_1()
{
print "inside fn"
}
BEGIN {   split(PARM_VAL,pa," "); 
}
FNR==NR{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[NR,i]=$i; }

{if (FILENAME == "SPP_OUT") {print $1}}
fn_1 
END {printf " second value of SPPIN : "a[2,2]} ' SPP_IN SPP_OUT"

Comment: @ candymanuu This issue is related to function

Comment: @vijayalakshmi-d Tried. Still facing same issue

Comment: @vijayalakshmid you can define a function anywhere in the code outside of a condition or action block. Before BEGIN, after BEGIN, after END,.... wherever.

Answer (score 4):

The function should be defined out of the `BEGIN` block. For example:

```
$ cat function.awk
function fib(n,  n_1, n_2)
{
    if (n < 2) {
        return n
    } else {
        n_1 = fib(n - 1)
        n_2 = fib(n - 2)
        return n_1 + n_2
    }
}

BEGIN {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        printf("fib(%d) = %d\n", i, fib(i));
    }
}
$ awk -f function.awk
fib(0) = 0
fib(1) = 1
fib(2) = 1
fib(3) = 2
fib(4) = 3
$
```

The user-defined `awk` function syntax is

```
function NAME(PARAMETER-LIST)
{
    BODY-OF-FUNCTION
}
```

The tricky part is:

> PARAMETER-LIST is a list of the function's **arguments and local variable
>   names**, separated by commas.  When the function is called, the argument
>   names are used to hold the argument values given in the call.  **The
>   local variables are initialized to the empty string**.  A function cannot
>   have two parameters with the same name, nor may it have a parameter
>   with the same name as the function itself.

See the [awk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Definition-Syntax.html#Definition-Syntax) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

To get the nucleus of your code working I had to add the `function` keyword when defining the function, and parentheses when making the call like so:

```
$ cat foo.awk
BEGIN { print "begin" }

function fn_1()
{
  print "inside fn"
}

{
    fn_1()
}

END { print "end" }

$ echo 'xyz' | awk -f foo.awk
begin
inside fn
end
```

From the awk manual:

> The definition of a function named name looks like this:
>
> **function** name(parameter-list)
>   {
>      body-of-function
>   }